# What is the proper way to extend a standard flutter widget when it has a hard coded theme such as the color of an icon?

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm wanting to change the color of the chevron used in the standard flutter widget **ExpansionPanel()**.  This is found in *packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_panel.dart*.

But I found that the icon color for this chevron is in one level below that in **ExpandIcon()**.  This is in *packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expand_icon.dart*

What is the proper way to pull that expand_icon.dart into my app and update/override just that hard coded color?

The color is defined like this:

```
  /// Default icon colors and opacities for when [Theme.brightness] is set to
  /// [Brightness.light] are based on the
  /// [Material Design system icon specifications](https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#color).
  /// Icon colors and opacities for [Brightness.dark] are based on the
  /// [Material Design dark theme specifications](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#ui-application)
  Color get _iconColor {
    if (widget.isExpanded && widget.expandedColor != null) {
      return widget.expandedColor;
    }

    if (widget.color != null) {
      return widget.color;
    }

    switch(Theme.of(context).brightness) {
      case Brightness.light:
        return Colors.black54;   // want to change this!!!
      case Brightness.dark:
        return Colors.white60;   // want to change this!!!

    }

    assert(false);
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `mixin` which is a "[class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) that contains methods for use by other classes without having to be the parent class of those other classes." Here is an example implementation allowing the class `Color` in your example above use a new method `getNewIconColor` where you can specify the colors you want to use.

```
mixin MyNewColors {
  get newIconColor {
    //...

    switch (Theme.of(context).brightness) {
      case Brightness.light:
        return Colors.orange; // or the colors you want to change!!!
      case Brightness.dark:
        return Colors.blue; // or colors you want to change!!!

    }

    // ...
  }
}

class MyColor extends Color with MyNewColors {
  // ···
}
```

Comment: I don't think that answers the question I asked though.  I was hoping for some elegant way 2 alter a standard widget without having to duplicate the entire set of official flutter files